# Set compiler for 1 package in Haskell Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to write a small web application fully in Haskell. I have 3 logical packages:

- A backend, using `servant`
- A frontend, using `reflex`, `reflex-dom` and `servant-reflex`
- A shared package defining the Servant API for communication between the 2 and some data types for that API to use.

That last package is giving me trouble. I don't know how to structure the project so the other 2 packages can use it. I see 2 options at the moment:

1. Each package has its own stack file and git repository. Import the shared package using an `extra-deps` git link. The problem with this approach is it means I have to push any change to the shared package to GitHub before I can test it out with the other packages. Also I'd have to build everything separately.
2. Use a single repository with a single stack.yml file. I'd prefer this, since it keeps everything together and also assures all packages are using the same resolver. In this case I would list all the packages in the `packages:` option. However, the client needs to be compiled with GHCJS, not GHC, and I don't see an option in the documentation to override the compiler for 1 specific package.

Is there a way to make option 2 work? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach is to have two stack project files (e.g. `stack-frontend.yaml` using GHCJS and `stack-backend.yaml` using GHC), and then use the `--stack-yaml` argument to switch between them (e.g. use `stack --stack-yaml=stack-frontend.yaml build` to build the frontend, and `stack --stack-yaml=stack-backend.yaml build` to build the backend).  Both `stack-*.yaml` files can include the shared servant API.